# What plant is this interesting yard weed?

Tags: lawn

[image]I'm wondering if anyone knows what this plant is growing in my yard in semi-shady areas in the mountain region of Virginia...that is the toe of my tennis shoe for size reference.

Comment: People will need your location listed above for ID attempts. :) Maybe also add another pic above with your finger or a coin for visual size reference?  Wondering what those brown, fallen  leaves are from. A tree? A bush? Probably doesn't matter. I'm just curious about the environment that it is growing in.

Comment: Do it smell of garlic? In any case, I think you should come here again in a few weeks, with larger leaves.

Comment: Giacomo...Garlic mustard?

Comment: @Diane, I like your questioning...don't be afraid to 'paint' outside the lines!

Comment: Mary, is that a Nike soft tennis shoe?  Almost like a dance shoe?  Haven't seen those for awhile.  Loved them.

Comment: Giacomo, garlic mustard's leaves are more heart shaped, not with all of these lobes.

Comment: Stormy, it's a Reebok Princess from many years ago.

Comment: Whatever it is, we have it in Ontario (Canada) and lady bugs love to make their nests in it. As I recall, multiple pink flowers on a stalk about not more than 24 inches tall, flowers in summer, cold hardy.

Answer (score 1):

Try Motherwort (*Leonurus cardiaca*) - most online images are of course of the flowers and flower stalks, but motherwort has similar rosette of leaves and knobbled leaf surface. https://www.minnesotawildflowers.info/flower/motherwort has a picture of leaves emerging in spring.